# to give permission in youtube api

Tags: python, youtube-api

When using **youtube-api analytics** to get info of a channel from my another email id, it told something like

> "You do not have permission to execute this method".

How do I give permission to the other email id to access my youtube-api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you have to make your other Google account [a Manager of the Google+ page of the channel](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3403100?hl=en%20manager). After you have done that, you will be able to retrieve data from that channel.

Comment: grt ..thnx .. and now am struggling to find my content owner id of my channel to retrive data .. have any idea ??

Comment: @hakunamatata Are you acting as a channel owner or as a Content Owner/CMS account? You can find your channel ID [here](https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced) and your Content Owner ID by navigating to the Content Owner dashboard and grabbing the ?o= value from the address bar.

Comment: done it clearly with  help of this link http://youtube-eng.blogspot.in/2013/05/find-hidden-patterns-with-youtubes-new_10.html